# Method PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\Button::confirm does not exist. Laravel Livewire Powergrid Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-livewire, livewires, livewire-powergrid

Method PowerComponents\LivewirePowerGrid\Button::confirm does not exist.

I using laravel powergrid table action buttons now i click delete delete button confirmation alert not working show this error

My Livewire Action code

```
public function actions(): array
    {
       return [
        Button::add('view')
        ->caption('Edit')
        ->target('_self')
        ->class('btn btn-primary')
        ->route('productedit', ['id' => 'id']),
    Button::make('delete', 'Delete')
    ->target('_self')
    ->class('btn btn-danger')
    ->confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')
    ->emit('productdelete', ['id' => 'id'])
        ];
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Livewire-Powergrid**, the confirm method of javascript cannot be directly called like this.
If you want to get confirmation on the click of delete button, you can **dispatch an event** on button click of powergrid & create a **listener in JS**. Then inside listener you may write simple javascript to generate a confirmation and proceed further actions against the response of confirmation.

Comment: it could benefit from a bit more specificity or an example to illustrate the process for users who might be less familiar with event handling in Livewire-Powergrid